# Failing to successfully run mariaDB on macos with brew

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb, homebrew

I have a mac version 12.5.1 and I am trying to install MariaDB with homebrew

I have followed this [guide](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-1-16-on-mac-os-x-with-homebrew/)

But when I get to running `mysql_install_db` I get:

`mysql.user table already exists! Run mariadb-upgrade, not mariadb-install-db`

Then when I run `mariadb-upgrade`

I get:
`Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed`

I have managed to log in with root but I cannot create any database

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE wp_new;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'wp_new'
```

If I try to run as sudo:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I try everything, not really sure how to give root full permission and grant privileges, nothing works

Comment: You have already installed a mysql instance on your Mac and this instance has a username and password. So to be able to do any changes on the database you need the credentials.
what happens if you just type
mysql -uroot

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: If I do mysql -u root -p now it works but  I get this on the prompt MariaDB [(none)]> then on Phpmyadmin I cannot create databases I get ` #1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'wp_new' `

Comment: select * from information_schema.user_privileges;
will show you which users are available and what they are allowed to do

Comment: GRANTEE : 'root'@'localhost'         |
TABLE_CATALOG: def  |
PRIVILEGE_TYPE: USAGE
IS_GRANTABLE: NO  
How can I grant all access

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';

Comment: ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'wp_new'. I also get this 
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You aren't running as root. [reset the root password](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#unable-to-connect-to-a-running-server-lost-root-password).

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed somehow, not really sure what really did it.

I uninstalled everything and installed it again.

I did put this on `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

And then

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new_password';
```

Eventually, it worked, not really sure why but I managed to run this command without sudo and then I was able to alter root.

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

All really weird, not sure yet what exactly did it